# Auto-resize a <div> image when there is a second <div> inside the main <div> wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a `.well.carousel` and inside that I have two `<div>`, one is the image and the other is the title text. I managed to auto-resize the image, but when I reduce the height of my `.well.carousel` then the title text falls out of the `.well.carousel`. How do I get the image to resize such that the title text also stays enclosed within `.well.carousel` when my height is 150px?

For example, attached [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/vy5re648/68/)

1. The height of `.well.carousel` is 150px, and the title text falls outside the well.
2. When I change the height to 300px, then the title text fall inside the well (even though the image height is 1300px!). I don't understand this.
3. If I change the width for `.well.carousel` from 400px to 100px you can see the image scale down. But if I keep the width at 400px but change only the height from 400px to 100px then nothing happens to the image. And here I want it to scale down too, same as when you change only the width.

HTML:

```
<div class="well carousel">
        <div class="image">
            <a href="placehold.it"><img alt="art-1" src=
            "http://placehold.it/1400x1300"></a></div>

        <div class="title">
            <a href="">title titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle title</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.well.carousel {
    height:150px;
    width:100px;
    border:5px solid #000000;
}

.title {
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333333;
    background-color:#FFF700;
}

.image {
    padding-bottom:5px
}

.image img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    display:block
}
```

Comment: Maybe to explain my question better: I updated my FIddle - If I change the width for well.carousel from 400px to 100px you see the image to scale down. But if I keep the width at 400px but change only the height from 400px to 100px then nothing happens to the image. ANd here I want it to scale down too, same as when you change only the width.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` and `flex-flow: column` on the container, then set `overflow: auto` and `flex: 1` on the text wrapper, and `flex: 2` on the image wrapper

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/vy5re648/72/))

```css
.well.carousel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
.title {
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFF700;
  flex: 1;
}
.image {
  flex: 2;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="well carousel">
  <div class="image">
    <a href="placehold.it">
      <img alt="art-1" src="http://placehold.it/1400x1300">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="title">
    <a href="">title titletitle titletitle titletitle titletitle title</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I manually change the height of the well.carousel then the image does not scale down. See my above comment also.

Answer (score 1):

**Well.** (no pun intended)

```
#outterelement { 
    position: relative; // Everything relative to me, right?
}

#elemant { 
  min-width: 100px; // pixels
  max-width: 300px; // pixels
  width: 100%; // leave % here
  max-height: 200px; // pixels
  min-width: 100px; // pixels
}
```

**Edit**: Due to comment below. Maybe I'm missing the point here; but I'm simply saying you can declare max and min properties in correlation with % and toggling position to keep all your elements within slider to 'respond' together without falling out of place; no matter what resolutions your supporting.

A very simple example of this:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vy5re648/74/)

Re-size the jsfiddle within your browser to see it respond without falling out of place.

**If you need more unique treatment**; CSS3 Media Queries are used define different styles per view-ports and resolutions:

*If you want the title to fill everything when under a small view-port.*

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   @-ms-viewport { width: 320px; }
   #title { 
       margin-top:-20px;
       min-height: 220px;
        }
}
```

Comment: toggle min-height: to large enough to fill! When under that CSS3 declared res

Comment: what I am after is that the image auto-resizes when I manually change the height of the well.carousel. If I did not have the <div> with the title text then it would work with my original code. But with the title text div included in the well.carousel I cannot get it to work (the image wont scale down like it would without the title text div).